# When will $\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}} {\sqrt{2}}$ be rational?

Tags: number-theory

For what n is this rational,
$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}} {\sqrt{2}}$$

So far I have found the integers 1,7,41 and I have found some rational solutions to this as well but I'm looking to get a more general sense.

- So when is this a rational number?
- Are there any restrictive properties that can be said about when this is rational? What can be said about n?

**Edit:** Thanks for the help on the integer solutions but is there anything that can be said about when it is *rational*?

Comment: There are infinitely many integer solutions to the Pell-type equation $2m^2-n^2=1$, including $n=1, 7, 41, 239, 1393, 8119, 47321, 275807, 1607521, 9369319$ et al.

Comment: thanks this is very helpful

Comment: I edited my answer for the general rational case, such as 23/7.  There are distinct solutions for all a,b where there is no common factor, a>b and one is even, 23/7 comes from (4,1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\dfrac{\sqrt{n^2+1}} {\sqrt{2}}$ is an *integer* $m$, then $\color{blue}{2m^2-n^2=1}$.

This is a Pell-type equation, and there are infinitely many solutions,

including $n=1, 7, 41, 239, 1393, 8119, 47321, 275807, 1607521, 9369319$ et al.

Comment: How about when m is rational?

Comment: If you want solutions with $m=\frac pq$, you would have to solve the generalized Pell equation $2p^2-r^2=q^2$ where $r=nq$

Comment: Do you know anything interesting about the solutions to the above?

Answer (score 2):

Well you want to solve for $n^2+1=2y^2$, this is a standard type of [Pell's Equation.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation)

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry I don't have much background in this. Does this account for all rational solutions?

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+1}}{\sqrt{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}{2}}$, which is rational if, and only if, $\sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}{2}}$ is an integer, so, there is $k \in \mathbb{N} : k^2 = \frac{n^2+1}{2}$

(Note that $\frac{n^2+1}{2}$ is either a reduced fraction or an integer)

If $n$ is even, there is no way it can happen, since $n^2+1$ will be an odd number and thus we won't get a perfect square

Comment: And if $n$ is odd....?

Comment: The first claim needs a justification

Comment: @fleablood We can't really tell. Either thing can happen

Comment: @lhf For any integer $m$, $\sqrt{m}$ is rational if and only if $\sqrt{m}$ is an integer

Comment: $\frac{n^2+1}{2}$ might not be an integer

Comment: If it's not an integer, then the numerator is necessarely an odd number, thus the result cannot be rational

Comment: $\frac{n^2+1}{2}$ might not be a reduced fraction.

Comment: @lhf In that case if would be an integer

Comment: Right! I suggest you add this argument to the answer. And we can clear the comments. Thanks.

Comment: My point is $n$ can't be even isn't a complete solution when $n$ may be odd.  And I agree with lhf that we can't say $\sqrt{\frac{n^2+1}n}$ is rational if and only if it is an integer. We should so it is rational if and only if $\frac {n^2+1}2$ in its reduced form has a perfect squares as it's numerator and denominator.  (e.g. $\sqrt{\frac{25}{36}}=\frac 56$ is rational).  So $2$ is not a square then to be rational it can't be in reduced form and $n^2 +1$ is even and $n$ is odd. and.... well, that's not a complete solution.

Answer (score 1):

This number is rational in the series 1, 7, 41, 239, ...

Each new number is t(n+1)=6 t(n)-t(n-1).

The feature works because 6^2-4 is a double-square,

EDIT:

There are a lot of solutions when it is rational, for example, putting x=23/7 will produce a rational result of 17/7.

This comes from the general pythagorus triangle $a^2-b^2 : 2ab : a^2+b^2 $.

From this, we multiply through by a rightangle (ie $1+i$), and we get

$(a^2-2ab-b^2)^2 + (a^2+2ab-b^2) = 2(a^2+b^2)^2$

This leads to the general solution:

$\frac 1{\sqrt{2}} \sqrt{(\frac{a^2+2ab-b^2}{a^2-2ab-b^2})^2+1} = \frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2-2ab-b^2}$

for all a, b that $2\mid ab$, $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a>b$.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. Sorry for any ignorance with the following question. When you refer to a,b. Are you referring to a rational number a/b? If so, $23*7 = 161$ and 161 is not divisible by two. Thanks in advance sorry for any lack of understanding.

Comment: Two numbers.  For the example of 23/7, we use 4 and 1, ie a=4, b=1.  This gives x=(16+8-1)/(16-8-1)=23/7.  The result is (16+1)/7 = 17/7.